# Changing text within a fabricjs context does not work

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to change the text inside the groups during an animation. You can see this in the console of the snippet below,

```
group.item(2).setText(Math.floor(count * 10) % 2 === 0 ? "O" : "X");
```

The `parseInt(count + "") % 2 === 0` could be the right manner to manage the flip of the coin text, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Can anyone help me to understand why the side of the coin doesn't flip?

```js
var fabric;
(function(fabric) {})(fabric || (fabric = {}));
fabric.Background = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
  type: "background",
  initialize: function(options) {
    options = options || {};
    this.callSuper("initialize", options);
  },
  _render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper("_render", ctx);
  }
});
var Ys = (function() {
  function Ys() {
    var _this = this;
    this.app = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById("c"));
    this.renderHexagram = function() {};
    this.resize = function() {
      var w = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
      var h = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;
      var width = w;
      var height = h;
      _this.app.setDimensions({
        width: width,
        height: height
      });
    };
    this.drawBackground = function() {
      var backgroundOptions = {};
      backgroundOptions.width = _this.app.getWidth();
      backgroundOptions.height = _this.app.getHeight();
      backgroundOptions.selectable = false;
      var background = new fabric.Background(backgroundOptions);
      var gradientOptions = _this.createVerticalGradientOptions("linear", _this.app.getHeight(), {
        0: "#333333",
        1: "#222222"
      });
      background.setGradient("fill", gradientOptions);
      _this.background = background;
      _this.app.add(background);
    };
    this.drawToss = function() {
      [1, 1, 1].forEach(function(item, idx) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          _this.toss(idx);
        }, _this.getRandom(1, 10) * 100);
      });
    };
    this.toss = function(idx) {
      var canvas = _this.app;
      var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        radius: (_this.app.getWidth() / 5) / 2,
        fill: "#FFE600",
        stroke: "#CACA3B",
        strokeWidth: 1,
        angle: 0,
        padding: 0,
        originX: "center",
        originY: "center"
      });
      var innerCircle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        radius: (_this.app.getWidth() / 6) / 2,
        fill: "#FFFF00",
        stroke: "#CACA3B",
        strokeWidth: 1.5,
        angle: 0,
        padding: 0,
        originX: "center",
        originY: "center"
      });
      var text = new fabric.Text("", {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        angle: 90,
        originX: "center",
        originY: "center",
        fill: "#fffdb5",
        stroke: "#CACA3B",
        fontSize: ((_this.app.getWidth() / 5)),
        fontWeight: 700,
        strokeWidth: 1
      });
      var group = new fabric.Group([circle, innerCircle, text], ({
        left: (_this.app.getWidth() / 6) + ((_this.app.getWidth() / 3) * idx),
        top: -((_this.app.getWidth() / 5) / 2),
        originX: "center",
        originY: "center",
        selectable: true,
        hasControl: true
      }));
      var rotateIntervall = setInterval((function() {
        var f = 0;
        return function() {
          group.angle = f;
          if (f > 180) {
            f = 0;
          } else {
            f += 1;
          }
          canvas.renderAll();
        };
      })(), 0);
      group.animate("top", _this.app.getHeight() - ((_this.app.getWidth() / 5) / 2), {
        duration: 600,
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
        easing: fabric.util.ease["easeOutBounce"]
      });
      (function rotate(f, count) {
        count += .01;
        console.log(Math.floor(count * 10));
        group.item(2).setText(Math.floor(count * 10) % 2 === 0 ? "O" : "X");
        var skewInterval = setInterval((function() {
          return function() {
            group.transformMatrix = [0, 1, f, 0, 0, 0];
            if (f > 1 && count >= 10) {
              clearInterval(skewInterval);
              clearInterval(rotateIntervall);
              return 0;
            } else if (f > 1) {
              f = 0;
            } else if (f > 0.8) {
              f += 0.03;
            } else if (f > 0.9) {
              if (f > 0.93) {
                f += 0.04;
              } else if (f > 0.96) {
                f += 0.05;
              } else {
                f += 0.06;
              }
            } else {
              f += 0.09;
            }
            canvas.renderAll();
            clearInterval(skewInterval);
            rotate(f, count);
            return 0;
          };
        })(), count);
      })(0, 0);
      canvas.add(group);
    };
    this.resize();
    this.app.renderOnAddRemove = true;
    this.headerHeight = this.app.getHeight() / 12;
    this.drawBackground();
    this.drawToss();
  }
  Ys.prototype.createVerticalGradientOptions = function(type, height, colorStops) {
    return {
      type: type,
      x1: 0,
      y1: 0,
      x2: 0,
      y2: height,
      colorStops: colorStops
    };
  };
  Ys.prototype.getRandom = function(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  };
  return Ys;
}());
var ys = new Ys();
//# sourceMappingURL=application.js.map
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Try `console.log()` calls to dump out the value of `count` and `(count * 10) % 2`. You're working with numbers less than 1 and `%` does things you probably don't expect.

Comment: Also `parseInt(count * 10 + "")` is strange; if you just want to make the value an integer use `Math.floor()` or `Math.round()`.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for your response, you are right, it was not very orthodox, but the problem doesn't seems the module result

Comment: Certainly a problem with the cache
try fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;

Comment: thanks @neopheus you was right, could you post an answer so that I can mark it like the right answer, please?

Comment: @Inferon it's do ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly a problem with the cache try :

```
fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;
```

```js
var fabric;
(function(fabric) {})(fabric || (fabric = {}));
fabric.Background = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
  type: "background",
  initialize: function(options) {
    options = options || {};
    this.callSuper("initialize", options);
  },
  _render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper("_render", ctx);
  }
});
var Ys = (function() {
  function Ys() {
    var _this = this;
    this.app = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById("c"));
    this.renderHexagram = function() {};
    this.resize = function() {
      var w = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
      var h = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;
      var width = w;
      var height = h;
      _this.app.setDimensions({
        width: width,
        height: height
      });
    };
    this.drawBackground = function() {
      var backgroundOptions = {};
      backgroundOptions.width = _this.app.getWidth();
      backgroundOptions.height = _this.app.getHeight();
      backgroundOptions.selectable = false;
      var background = new fabric.Background(backgroundOptions);
      var gradientOptions = _this.createVerticalGradientOptions("linear", _this.app.getHeight(), {
        0: "#333333",
        1: "#222222"
      });
      background.setGradient("fill", gradientOptions);
      _this.background = background;
      _this.app.add(background);
    };
    this.drawToss = function() {
      [1, 1, 1].forEach(function(item, idx) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          _this.toss(idx);
        }, _this.getRandom(1, 10) * 100);
      });
    };
    this.toss = function(idx) {
      var canvas = _this.app;
      var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        radius: (_this.app.getWidth() / 5) / 2,
        fill: "#FFE600",
        stroke: "#CACA3B",
        strokeWidth: 1,
        angle: 0,
        padding: 0,
        originX: "center",
        originY: "center"
      });
      var innerCircle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        radius: (_this.app.getWidth() / 6) / 2,
        fill: "#FFFF00",
        stroke: "#CACA3B",
        strokeWidth: 1.5,
        angle: 0,
        padding: 0,
        originX: "center",
        originY: "center"
      });
      var text = new fabric.IText("", {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        angle: 90,
        originX: "center",
        originY: "center",
        fill: "#fffdb5",
        stroke: "#CACA3B",
        fontSize: ((_this.app.getWidth() / 6)),
        fontFamily: "Segoe UI",
        fontWeight: 700,
        strokeWidth: 1
      });
      var group = new fabric.Group([circle, innerCircle, text], ({
        left: (_this.app.getWidth() / 6) + ((_this.app.getWidth() / 3) * idx),
        top: -((_this.app.getWidth() / 5) / 2),
        originX: "center",
        originY: "center",
        selectable: true,
        hasControl: true
      }));
      var rotateIntervall = setInterval((function() {
        var f = 0;
        return function() {
          group.angle = f;
          if (f > 180) {
            f = 0;
          } else {
            f += 1;
          }
          canvas.renderAll();
        };
      })(), 0);
      group.animate("top", _this.app.getHeight() - ((_this.app.getWidth() / 5) / 2), {
        duration: 600,
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
        easing: fabric.util.ease["easeOutBounce"]
      });
      (function rotate(f, count) {
        count += .01;
        group.item(2).set({
          text: Math.floor(count * 10) % 2 === 0 ? "I" : "O"
        });
        var skewInterval = setInterval((function() {
          return function() {
            group.transformMatrix = [0, 1, f, 0, 0, 0];
            if (f > 1 && count >= 10) {
              clearInterval(skewInterval);
              clearInterval(rotateIntervall);
              return 0;
            } else if (f > 1) {
              f = 0;
            } else if (f > 0.8) {
              f += 0.03;
            } else if (f > 0.9) {
              if (f > 0.93) {
                f += 0.04;
              } else if (f > 0.96) {
                f += 0.05;
              } else {
                f += 0.06;
              }
            } else {
              f += 0.09;
            }
            canvas.renderAll();
            clearInterval(skewInterval);
            rotate(f, count);
            return 0;
          };
        })(), count);
      })(0, 0);
      canvas.add(group);
    };
    fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;
    this.resize();
    this.app.renderOnAddRemove = true;
    this.headerHeight = this.app.getHeight() / 12;
    this.drawBackground();
    this.drawToss();
  }
  Ys.prototype.createVerticalGradientOptions = function(type, height, colorStops) {
    return {
      type: type,
      x1: 0,
      y1: 0,
      x2: 0,
      y2: height,
      colorStops: colorStops
    };
  };
  Ys.prototype.getRandom = function(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  };
  return Ys;
}());
var ys = new Ys();
//# sourceMappingURL=application.js.map
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```